# how to handle website which req. Domain Validated SSL certificate to login using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, ssl-certificate

I want to know how can I select Domain Validated SSL certificate to login into a website. While I run selenium code, I'm unable to accept the only displayed certificate. What is the best way to handle such cases.

[image: Pop UP]

Comment: How can I change this certificate into trusted certificate so that I don't have to select it again and again or is their any way to accept the same via code. I don't want to use GUI as it appear multiple times in one session.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **`acceptInsecureCerts`** capability:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.set_capability("acceptInsecureCerts",True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Comment: Nope it didn't worked. It's getting stuck and I have to manually accept it